# DBpedia Sparql not giving all places

Tags: sparql, wikipedia, dbpedia, wikidata

I am trying to dump all dbpedia places in my database.

But when I checked my Dump places, **it is missing some places.** Like **Eiffel_Tower** and **Taj_Mahal**.

I thing below query is not giving all places.

In below query I am incrementing **offset**  by **10000** till end of **dbo:Place** Count

```
SELECT ?place ?wikiPageID ?wikiPageRevisionID WHERE  { 
  ?place a dbo:Place .
  ?place dbo:wikiPageID ?wikiPageID .
  ?place dbo:wikiPageRevisionID ?wikiPageRevisionID .
}
limit 10000 offset 0
```

I thought I will get all Places from DBpedia but it is missing many places.
My main aim is to get all places of wikipedia.

Please help me.

Comment: Which are missing (any concrete example about a missing place)? Have you tried `order by` (not sure this is necessary, I never tried dbpedia myself)?

Comment: Only 40000 are allowed for `order by` SORT

Comment: I have not found Eiffel_Tower, Taj_Mahal... but according to me this places are exist in `dbo:Place`.  I figure out this because this places are popular and not showing. Right now I have 826484 places in my dump database

Comment: I tried to do some diagnosis with the following, but it didn't lead me to any solution yet:  `SELECT * WHERE  { 
values ?place { <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Taj_Mahal> } .
  ?place a dbo:Place .
  optional { ?place dbo:wikiPageID ?wikiPageID } .
  optional { ?place dbo:wikiPageRevisionID ?wikiPageRevisionID } .
}`

Comment: Ok no problem, please provide any other option to Get all **WikiPedia Places**

Comment: What exactly is the problem now?

Comment: 1. If you use a local Virtuoso instance, you can increase the max. number of returned rows in the `virtuoso.ini`

Comment: 2. If you use the public DBpedia endpoint, you can use `LIMIT` + `OFFSET`. If you also need `ORDER BY`, you have to use a workaround in a sub-`SELECT`: `select * {
{SELECT ?place ?wikiPageID ?wikiPageRevisionID WHERE  { 
  ?place a dbo:Place .
  ?place dbo:wikiPageID ?wikiPageID .
  ?place dbo:wikiPageRevisionID ?wikiPageRevisionID .
}
order by desc(?place)
}
}
limit 10000 offset 40000`

Comment: Or again, if you have a local Virtuoso server, in the `virtuoso.ini` increase the parameter `MaxSortedTopRows` to avoid the `ORDER BY` limitations.

Comment: Does this solve the problem or is there something different that I overlooked in the question?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions... But Could you suggest other than DBpedia Sparql.

Comment: I can't follow you. What's wrong with my suggestions? Those give you all places in DBpedia.

Comment: Perhaps you just want the [full dataset dumps](http://wiki.dbpedia.org/datasets/dbpedia-version-2016-10)? Or [your own DBpedia in the cloud](https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/B012DSCFEK)?

Comment: @AKSW your suggestions are very useful for me. It solved my problem, I was asking you to know is there any other way to get places. Thanks once again for your help.

Comment: Wikidata would be another dataset which contains cross-domain data.